# How can I control the Apple Push Notifications I receive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have successfully created a server that sends Apple Push Notifications, and my iphone receives them.

For example I have Notification of type A and notifications of type B,

How can I control the types of notifications I received on the iphone side? For example I only want type A and not B (Just like Facebook, I want notifications for Friend Request, but not for Walls)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot stop your device on receiving a specific type of notification unless it is done on server side. Though you can ignore a notification when app is in running state as you get the notification in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and you can simply ignore it after checking it but if app is in background or it is closed then you cannot control the incoming notifications from within your app.

you can make a service on server to set preferences for notification types.
from device, user can enable/disable the push service for individual features and update the preferences on server from device.

On server, before sending the PUSH, you can check for the preferences selected by user from the table and send only those notifications which the user has opted for.